# -bash: ./configure: No such file or directory - MySQL install on Mac OS X 10.6

Tags: mysql, macos

I'm trying to install MySQL on Mac OS X 10.6.   After I download MySQL and untar with tar xzvf mysql-5.1.37.tar.gz I then try and run this configure line:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/mysql --with-extra-charsets=complex --enable-thread-safe-client --enable-local-infile --enable-shared --with-plugins=innobase
```

I get the error

> -bash: ./configure: No such file or director

I thought that configure should be a file in directory `mysql`, but it is not there. Am I correct, or is configure something else?

Comment: find ./ | grep configure

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You've downloaded the binary version, not the source.

This is the reason that you're getting the config error. Go here:

http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?117,295428,295493#msg-295493

for the correct mysql version to compile from source.

Answer (score 4):

I was having a similar problem (mysql 5.5.23), which seems to be caused by the fact that they decided to switch to using cmake from autotools.

[MySQL ::   MySQL Internals Manual :: 4.6.6 ./configure Emulation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/configure-emulation.html)

Answer (score 2):

Did you actually `cd mysql-5.1.37` before trying to run `./configure`?

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget to

cd mysql-5.1.37

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, you verified the file is there, right?  You might have to set the execute bit:

```
chmod 755 configure
```

Comment: you'd actually get "permission denied" if you tried to execute that.  He's probably just in the wrong directory, or perhaps needs to run autoreconf.

Comment: @John: It matches what?  My point is that ./configure won't work unless the file has execute permission.  That what chmod 755 sets, along with read permission for everyone and write permission for the owner.

Comment: Thanks Wallyk, I installed via Macports in the end, but my problem was that the file wasn't there, so I couldn't have set the permissions anyhow.

Answer (score 0):

The file should be there. It's in the archived version I just downloaded. You might want to grab another copy and try again.

Comment: Yes I am in the right directory.  No the file is not actually there, I tried two different mirrors, the San Jose one and the [Hurricane Electric / San Jose, CA]  and the [Semaphore Corporation, Seattle, WA]

from this link:
 http://dev.mysql.com/get/Downloads/MySQL-5.1/mysql-5.1.40-osx10.5-powerpc-64bit.tar.gz/from/pick?file=Downloads/MySQL-5.1/mysql-5.1.40-osx10.5-powerpc-64bit.tar.gz&mirror=pick

Am I going mad?

Comment: grep gives the only file with configure in the name within that folder as: .//support-files/binary-configure

Comment: What's the output of: find /YourUnpackedMySQLDir -name 'configure'

Comment: @Pestilence the output is nothing from that command.  I tried another 2 tar files, but they also do not have the .configure file in them.