# MySQL source code is missing configure file

Tags: mysql, macos, installation, configure

I'm trying to compile MySQL from source on Mac OS X 10.5.  I downloaded what I believe to be the correct source code from the "Source Code" section on [MySQL's download page](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/).  The label on it reads "Generic Linux (Architecture Independent), Compressed TAR Archive"; the file's available [here](http://dev.mysql.com/get/Downloads/MySQL-5.5/mysql-5.5.9.tar.gz/from/http://mysql.mirrors.hoobly.com/).

This question is really similar to another question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1910356/bash-configure-no-such-file-or-directory-mysql-install-on-mac-os-x-10-6), but that question is outdated and hasn't helped me.  Its answer proposes that I've "downloaded the binary version, not the source."  If I don't have the right download, can someone point me in the right direction?

When I unarchive the tar.gz file, there is no file named `configure`.  Here's what the directory looks like:

```
drwxrwxrwx@  63 xxxx xxxx    2142 Jan 19 15:37 BUILD
-rw-rw-rw-@   1 xxxx xxxx    8479 Jan 19 15:37 BUILD-CMAKE
-rw-rw-rw-@   1 xxxx xxxx   12080 Jan 19 15:37 CMakeLists.txt
-rw-rw-rw-@   1 xxxx xxxx   17987 Jan 19 15:37 COPYING
drwxrwxrwx@   9 xxxx xxxx     306 Jan 19 15:37 Docs
-rw-rw-rw-@   1 xxxx xxxx  342250 Jan 19 15:37 INSTALL-SOURCE
-rw-rw-rw-@   1 xxxx xxxx     324 Jan 19 15:37 INSTALL-WIN-SOURCE
-rw-rw-rw-@   1 xxxx xxxx  113534 Jan 19 15:37 README
-rw-rw-rw-@   1 xxxx xxxx      87 Jan 19 15:37 VERSION
drwxrwxrwx@  22 xxxx xxxx     748 Jan 19 15:37 client
drwxrwxrwx@  33 xxxx xxxx    1122 Jan 19 15:37 cmake
drwxrwxrwx@   4 xxxx xxxx     136 Jan 19 15:37 cmd-line-utils
-rw-rw-rw-@   1 xxxx xxxx   18312 Jan 19 15:37 config.h.cmake
-rw-rw-rw-@   1 xxxx xxxx   33945 Jan 19 15:37 configure.cmake
drwxrwxrwx@  18 xxxx xxxx     612 Jan 19 15:37 dbug
drwxrwxrwx@  13 xxxx xxxx     442 Jan 19 15:37 extra
drwxrwxrwx@  72 xxxx xxxx    2448 Jan 19 15:37 include
drwxrwxrwx@  10 xxxx xxxx     340 Jan 19 15:37 libmysql
drwxrwxrwx@  12 xxxx xxxx     408 Jan 19 15:37 libmysqld
drwxrwxrwx@   8 xxxx xxxx     272 Jan 19 15:37 libservices
drwxrwxrwx@  50 xxxx xxxx    1700 Jan 19 15:37 man
drwxrwxrwx@  19 xxxx xxxx     646 Jan 19 15:37 mysql-test
drwxrwxrwx@ 123 xxxx xxxx    4182 Jan 19 15:37 mysys
drwxrwxrwx@   3 xxxx xxxx     102 Jan 19 15:37 packaging
drwxrwxrwx@   7 xxxx xxxx     238 Jan 19 15:37 plugin
drwxrwxrwx@  30 xxxx xxxx    1020 Jan 19 15:37 regex
drwxrwxrwx@  31 xxxx xxxx    1054 Jan 19 15:37 scripts
drwxrwxrwx@ 303 xxxx xxxx   10302 Jan 19 15:37 sql
drwxrwxrwx@  35 xxxx xxxx    1190 Jan 19 15:37 sql-bench
drwxrwxrwx@   7 xxxx xxxx     238 Jan 19 15:37 sql-common
drwxrwxrwx@  13 xxxx xxxx     442 Jan 19 15:37 storage
drwxrwxrwx@  59 xxxx xxxx    2006 Jan 19 15:37 strings
drwxrwxrwx@  27 xxxx xxxx     918 Jan 19 15:37 support-files
drwxrwxrwx@  37 xxxx xxxx    1258 Jan 19 15:37 tests
drwxrwxrwx@   8 xxxx xxxx     272 Jan 19 15:37 unittest
drwxrwxrwx@  15 xxxx xxxx     510 Jan 19 15:37 vio
drwxrwxrwx@   3 xxxx xxxx     102 Jan 19 15:37 win
drwxrwxrwx@  32 xxxx xxxx    1088 Jan 19 15:37 zlib
```

`find . -name 'configure'` returns nothing.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Type `cmake` to build MySQL. This is described in the instructions for [installing from source](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/installing-source-distribution.html). (I assume this is also explained in the `INSTALL` or `README` files in the tarball, but I'm having difficulties downloading the tarball.)

Comment: Aha, silly me. It seems I was looking at documentation for 5.1 instead of 5.5. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You've downloaded the ***binary*** version, not the ***source***.

This is the reason that you're getting the config error.

:)